# button onclicklistener error

Tags: android

i'm getting this error when i try to run my app in the emulator (any android version): **java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.test/com.android.test.HomeScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException**

**my question is:** is this because in 2.2 there is no "golf button" in the layout, and in 3.0 there is?

this is my activity:

```
public class HomeScreen extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homescreen);

    Button basketball = (Button)findViewById(R.id.basketball);

    basketball.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent basketball = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, basketball.class);
        startActivity(basketball);
        }
    });

    Button golf = (Button)findViewById(R.id.golf);

    golf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent golf = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, golf.class);
        startActivity(golf);
        }
    });
}
}
```

i got 2 layouts

layout 1: **layout-normal-mdpi** <= running in 2.2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/homescreen">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/basketball"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/basketbal"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

layout 2: **xlarge-port** <= running in 3.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/homescreen">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/basketball"
        android:background="@drawable/basketbal"
        android:layout_height="225dp"
        android:layout_width="225dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/golf"
        android:background="@drawable/golf"
        android:layout_height="550dp"
        android:layout_width="211dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="390dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes. If you your layout shouldn't have a `golf button` in normal layout, you should check if `findViewById()` returns null. You should also provide a full stacktrace and mark the line in the code that throws it... its easier for us to help you than.

Comment: @WarrenFaith but if i delete this `Button golf = (Button)findViewById(R.id.golf); golf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) { Intent golf = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, golf.class); startActivity(golf); } });` then it runs perfect.

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting error in the below line,

```
Button golf = (Button)findViewById(R.id.golf);
```

which is not actually present in the first layout you have provided here, it is no wonder. This definitely doesn't exist and which obviously returns null to you and there you go, getting null pointer exception.

To avoid this either you have to catch the exception else you will have change the layout accordingly such that it contains both the buttons in both the layouts.

Comment: Catching an exception is expensive. So catching a NPE is overkill. A simple null check should be enough...

Comment: if i remove the golf button setonclicklistener the app runs perfect

Comment: ya exactly. both your layouts should be identical in terms of "id" and widgets, if not android will generate null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You're lacking golf button in your first layout, as you stated.
So, when you run

```
Button golf = (Button)findViewById(R.id.golf);
golf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

golf is set to null (first line) and then you're trying to assign it something...
Try this:

```
Button golf = (Button)findViewById(R.id.golf);
  if (golf != null) {
    golf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

**EDITED:**
Put these lines in your 2.2 layout:

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/golf"
  android:visibility="invisible"
  android:layout_height="1dp"
  android:layout_width="1dp"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
</Button>
```

With attribute `visibility="invisible"` your app should work and your layout shouldn't be wasted

Comment: i did that still the same error but in my opinion there is something wrong with the activity class. but i don't know what. if i remove the golf button setonclicklistener the app runs perfect

Comment: @TheHunter: Please update the layouts and the code in your question to what you have now. Also include the stacktrace and mark the line in the code where the error appears!